# Parsing XML file on Google Sheet via Google Drive

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for an help for our team.

Our need:

- Need to parse a xml file that is located on Google Drive
- We will be using Google Sheet to read datas
- We tried to parse the file with =importxml(“https://drive.google.com/uc?id=**###FILEID###**&export=download”, “//*") formula but didn't work.
- We guess there's a little script to code, but we have no knowledge on this.
- We just need a script to read all datas in a spreadsheet.

Can you help us? Thank you in advance!

M

Comment: What data do you need from the XML? A single value? A group of values? Also, could you provide the XML structure?

Comment: Hi Martì! I need to get a group of values. Part of XML is this: 

 <Worksheet ss:Name="Righe">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="20" ss:ExpandedRowCount="38" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1">
   <Row ss:Height="15.75">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Modifica - Piano Giri - 21G0859</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:Height="63.75">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Column 1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">Value 1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the second parameter (`"//*"`) to the path where the information is. The syntax of that is called `XPath` and there are a few online tutorials about it.

### References

- [IMPORTXML function (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)